# Amazon S3 Write Only access

Tags: permissions, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm backing up files from several customers directly into an Amazon S3 bucket - each customer to a different folder. I'm using a simple .Net client running under a Windows task once a night. To allow writing to the bucket, my client requires both the AWS access key and the secret key (I created a new pair).

My problem is:

1. How do I make sure none of my customers could potentially use the pair to peek in the bucket and in a folder not his own? Can I create a "write only" access pair?
2. Am I approaching this the right way? Should this be solved through AWS access settings, or should I client-side encrypt files on the customer's machine (each customer with a different key) prior to uploading and avoid a the above mentioned cross-access?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use IAM to create a separate user for each customer (not just an additional key pair), then give each user access to only their S3 folder. For instance, if the bucket is called `everybodysbucket`, and customer A's files all start with `userA/` (and customer B's with `userB/`), then you can grant permission to `everybodysbucket/userA/*` to the user for customer A, and to `everybodysbucket/userB/*` for customer B.

That will prevent each user from seeing any resources not their own.

Use can also control specific S3 operations, not just resources, that each user can access. So yes, you can grant write-only permission to the users if you want.

Comment: So does that mean I'll use the same key pair for all users, or will I generate a new pair per IAM user?

Comment: Each IAM user will have a different key pair.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, created a user, added a policy with  various "S3::" actions to a resource "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/folder/user/*" and I get "access denied" errors. If I change the user policy to "arn:aws:s3:::*" it works. Do I also need to set a bucket policy to allow a user to write to his folder?

Comment: I just tried it, and it worked. My user had a single S3 permission: `PutObject`, with the ARN similar to the one above. I was able to create an object in that folder. Are you sure that the object you are creating in "my_bucket" is named "folder/user/somethingorother"?

Comment: yep. But I managed to find the problem - somewhere in the code some genius decided to check whether the directory structure exists by using GetObject, so he was basically looking for the parent folder - for which the user has no permission. Thanks for your answer - it solved my issue.

Comment: Note, however, you can only have a [maximum of 500 API keys per account per region](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html) (in case you want to use this technique on a larger number of customers)

Answer (score 18):

I just created a write-only policy like this and it seems to be working:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I think creating a drop like that is a much neater solution.

Comment: This worked for me when I changed the action to: "s3:PutObject*" (ie added an asterix) HTH

Answer (score 0):

As a variation on the approach recommended in [Charles' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15077470/18192), you can also manage access control at the user level via SFTP.  These users can all share the same global IAM policy:

- SFTP does support user-specific home directories (akin to "chroot").
- SFTP allows you to manage user access via service managed authentication or via your own authentication provider.  I am unsure if service managed authentication has user limits.
- If you wish to allow users to access uploaded files using a client, SFTP provides it very cleanly.