# Java AWS SDK - How to upload file using IAM profile from Java API

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I have just started using AWS for my project. I want to write a project that uploads critical files to s3 bucket. I donot want to expose any secret keys so that all other developers / users can access the uploaded documents. Please provide some pointer how to begin with.

My Current Implementation:

```
 return new AmazonS3Client(new AWSCredentials() {
    @Override
    public String getAWSAccessKeyId() {
    return accessKey;
    }

   @Override
   public String getAWSSecretKey() {
     return accessKeySecret;
   }, clientConfiguration )
```

Then I use  amazonS3Client.putObject(putReq); to upload file.
So, here I am exposing my keys that enables other colleague to download/view the files. Anyone can use it to download/upload file from s3cmd, browser plugins etc.

On reading AWS docs, I got to know I can use EC2 instance and setup IAM profile. BUt I am not sure how can I do with java code. Please provide some link and example

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076645/amazon-s3-write-only-access This question gives each user a separate folder in the S3 bucket - users do not have access to each others folders

Comment: I think the question focuses more on how to get credentials from an instance's IAM role.

Comment: That wouldn't prevent 'exposing my keys that enables other colleague to download/view the files', would it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.html) class. It gets IAM credentials (access/secret key) from the instance's metadata. Launch your instance under an IAM role that has a policy that permits access to S3.

> AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
>                         .withCredentials(new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider())
>                         .build();

[Source reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/java-dg-roles.html)